# .NET RegEx: Find function and validate

Tags: c#, .net, regex

In the project I'm currently working on signals from various sources are captured in triggered events. To analize the signals we want to use some querying and came up with a naming convention for our signals. We want to use RegEx to validate the conformity aswell as split off the individual parts of the Signal string.

Signals are required to have the following structure:

```
Function(SignalName@Time)
```

Function and @Time are optional, however SignalName is always required.

Some exsamples of what that might look like:

```
Corp.Signals.LivingRoom.Temperature@TStart   //temperature of living room at start of event
Corp.Signals.LivingRoom.Temperature          //missing time stamp will default to start of event
int(Corp.Signals.BedRoom.NoiseLevel@T+4.20)  //integral of bed room noise from Start to 4.20 seconds into the event
Corp.Signals.Kitchen.Light@TEnd-.5           //state of the kitchen light 0.5 seconds before the end of the event
```

So far I came up with this RegEx:

```
(?<open>(?<function>\w+)\(|)(?<signal>Corp\.Signals\.\w+\.\w+)(?:@T(?<time>((Start|Mid|End|)([-+]\d?(\.\d+)?)?))|)(?<-open>\)|)
```

This works pretty ok so far, but still matches strings that are not part of the nameing scheme.

1. Signals without function but with closing parentheses at the end:

   `Corp.Signals.BedRoom.NoiseLevel@T+4)`

   I'm not sure why this is consumed, as the "open" balancing group didn't capture anything. How can a parenteses at the end be consumed?
2. Signals that have a function, but are missing the closing parenteses.

   `int(Corp.Signals.LivingRoom.Temperature@T-.2`
3. Signals with only partial timestamp(missing time)

   `Corp.Signals.LivingRoom.Temperature@T+`

[Example on RegEx Storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3Copen%3E%28%3F%3Cfunction%3E%5Cw%2B%29%5C%28%7C%29%28%3F%3Csignal%3ECorp%5C.Signals%5C.%5Cw%2B%5C.%5Cw%2B%29%28%3F%3A%40T%28%3F%3Ctime%3E%28%28Start%7CMid%7CEnd%7C%29%28%5B-%2B%5D%5Cd%3F%28%5C.%5Cd%2B%29%3F%29%3F%29%29%7C%29%28%3F%3C-open%3E%5C%29%7C%29&i=Corp.Signals.LivingRoom.Temperature%40TStart%0D%0Aint%28Corp.Signals.BedRoom.NoiseLevel%40T%2B4%29%0D%0ACorp.Signals.LivingRoom.Temperature%40TMid%2B2.3%0D%0ACorp.Signals.LivingRoom.Temperature%0D%0A%0D%0ACorp.Signals.LivingRoom.Temperature%40T%2B%0D%0ACorp.Signals.BedRoom.NoiseLevel%40T%2B4%29%0D%0Aint%28Corp.Signals.LivingRoom.Temperature%40T-.2%0D%0A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might do is use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match either the part with the function and the open and closing parenthesis, or match the part without it matching only the signal the the optional time.

In the alternation you can use the same group names which is supported by C#.

```
(?<!\S)(?:(?<function>\w+)\((?<signal>Corp\.Signals(?:\.\w+)*)(?:@T(?<time>(?:Start|Mid|End)?(?:[-+](?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?|\.\d+))?)?\)|(?<signal>Corp\.Signals(?:\.\w+)*)(?:@T(?<time>(?:Start|Mid|End)?(?:[-+](?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+))?)?)?)(?!\S)
```

In large parts to see the named groups `function`, `signal` and `time`

- `(?<!\S)` Assert what is on the left is not a non whitespace char
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?<function>\w+)`
  - `\(` Match opening parenthesis
  - `(?<signal>Corp\.Signals(?:\.\w+)*)`
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `@T(?<time>(?:Start|Mid|End)?(?:[-+](?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?|\.\d+))?`
  - `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
  - `\)` Match closing parenthesis
  - `|` Or
  - `(?<signal>Corp\.Signals(?:\.\w+)*)(?:@T(?<time>(?:Start|Mid|End)?(?:[-+](?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+))?)?)?` Same as previous part without the function and parenthesis
- `)`
- `(?!\S)` Assert what is on the right is not a non whitespace char

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cS%29%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3cfunction%3e%5cw%2b%29%5c%28%28%3f%3csignal%3eCorp%5c.Signals%28%3f%3a%5c.%5cw%2b%29*%29%28%3f%3a%40T%28%3f%3ctime%3e%28%3f%3aStart%7cMid%7cEnd%29%3f%28%3f%3a%5b-%2b%5d%28%3f%3a%5cd%2b%28%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%2b%29%3f%29%3f%7c%5c.%5cd%2b%29%29%3f%29%3f%5c%29%7c%28%3f%3csignal%3eCorp%5c.Signals%28%3f%3a%5c.%5cw%2b%29*%29%28%3f%3a%40T%28%3f%3ctime%3e%28%3f%3aStart%7cMid%7cEnd%29%3f%28%3f%3a%5b-%2b%5d%28%3f%3a%5cd%2b%28%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%2b%29%3f%7c%5c.%5cd%2b%29%29%3f%29%3f%29%3f%29%28%3f!%5cS%29&i=Corp.Signals.LivingRoom.Temperature%40TStart%0d%0aCorp.Signals.LivingRoom.Temperature%0d%0aint%28Corp.Signals.BedRoom.NoiseLevel%40T%2b4.20%29%0d%0aCorp.Signals.Kitchen.Light%40TEnd-.5%0d%0aint%28Corp.Signals.BedRoom.NoiseLevel%40T%2b4%29%0d%0aint%28Corp.Signals.BedRoom.NoiseLevel%29%0d%0aCorp.Signals.LivingRoom.Temperature%40TMid%2b2.3%0d%0a%0d%0aCorp.Signals.BedRoom.NoiseLevel%40T%2b4%29%0d%0aint%28Corp.Signals.LivingRoom.Temperature%40T-.2%0d%0aCorp.Signals.LivingRoom.Temperature%40T%2b&o=m)

[image]

Comment: I hoped that I could avoid reusing the same pattern in an alternation. If only .Net RegEx would allow defines like PCRE. Anyways your answer was a great help. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try following :

```
            string[] inputs = {
                "Corp.Signals.LivingRoom.Temperature@TStart",
                "int(Corp.Signals.BedRoom.NoiseLevel@T+4)",
                "Corp.Signals.LivingRoom.Temperature@TMid+2.3",
                "Corp.Signals.LivingRoom.Temperature",
                "Corp.Signals.LivingRoom.Temperature@T+",
                "Corp.Signals.BedRoom.NoiseLevel@T+4)",
                "int(Corp.Signals.LivingRoom.Temperature@T-.2"
                              };

            //Function(SignalName@Time) sample, Function and Time optional
            string pattern = @"^((\w[\w.]+(@T(([+-](\d+|\d*.\d+))|\w+))?)|(\w+\(\w[\w.]+(@T(([+-](\d+|\d*.\d+))|\w+))?\)))$";

            foreach (string input in inputs)
            {
                Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
                Console.WriteLine("Success : {0}, Expression : '{1}'", match.Success, input); 
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```